# Как убрать нумерацию в QTableWidget?

Tags: qt

При выводе таблицы, по умолчанию и нумерация строк и столбцов. Мне нужно чтобы этого не происходило. Я нашёл на форумах следующие инструкции:

table->horizontalHeader()->hide();

table->verticalHeader()->hide();

а так же,

table->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(false);

table->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);

но в моём случае, компилятор ругается на эти строки. Знаю, возможно очень глупая ошибка, но в упор не могу понять куда ниточка тянется.

[image: Скриншот кода]

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решился подключением QHeaderView в заголовке класса. Странно, он должен был содержаться в QTableWidget, даже QtCreator подсвечивал всё что надо. Но главное что дело ниточка вытянулась, надеюсь, лишь, что не криво)

Answer (score 0):

Вот одно из решений возможно пригодиться.

```
QStringList tmp_list; tmp_list << "" << ""<< ""<< ""<< ""; // где количество пустых строк равняется количеству столбиков.
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(tmp_list);
```

со строками необходимо провести аналогичные манипуляции. В дальнейшем вы можете заменить пустые строки на необходимые названия.

Answer (score 0):

У меня не работает, как вы написали. Ссылается на невозможность использование << знака.

Выход нашелся сам собой, используйте метод:

```
list->push_front("Имя"); 
list->push_back("Фамилия"); 
list->push_back("Отчество");
```

где QStringList *list и потом:

```
table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(*list);
```

где QTableWidget *table.